# What is the best Linux Crypto currency mining program to use that doesn't require a GPU?

Tags: currency, mining

Under my question, it is clearly stated
`The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed`

My apologies if my question is subjective to the point where it is closed. I didn't not mean to violate or break any rules.

I have a bunch of E-3 machines that can be utilized to mine but they do not have GPU's attached to them. They are 1U racked server machines.

Can someone be a sport and point me ion the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with [CPUMiner](https://github.com/tpruvot/cpuminer-multi)

AFAIK, currently Monero mining with Cryptonight algorithm is most profitable.

Comment: Right on mate. I appreciate you. I will research and post my findings as this may help others.